# Sphinx automated image numbering/captions?

Tags: python, templates, python-sphinx

Is there a way to automatically generate an image/figure caption using sphinx?

I currently have rest-sphinx files I'm converting to html and (latex)pdf using sphinx.

I'd like an easy way for users to reference a specific image in the resulting html/pdf files.
For example, if a user is refering to the documentation in an email, "In 'Image 65' it says XXX, but this doesn't work for me".

I've tried using [figure](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#id15) where it appears to allow you to apply a caption to an image, but this has to be manually added. (And I have problems getting it to work with substitution for some reason).

Is there a rest-sphinx method I'm overlooking that would achieve this?
Or, is there a way to modify/edit sphinx's existing templates to add this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx consumes reStructuredText as templated by [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com). According to the Sphinx documentation though, you [have other templating options](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html).

You should be able to use Jinja's [control structures](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures) in a custom template to achieve the effect you're after.